# Extracting Excel files from Multiple subfolders and load them into sql server table basing on city name

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a folder which contain's Sub folders(City Names) and in those sub folders I have excel files. I have to take all the excel files from the sub folder and load them into a SQL Server table basing on the city name. The files are structured as below.

Dallas Folder contain's these files

- DALLAS_Cars_2011.xls
- DALLAS_Trucks_2011.xls
- DALLAS_Bikes_2011.xls

My requirement is I have to load the cars data into cars table and Trucks data into Trucks tables, basing on their names and all the city file's should go into same table like cars's, trucks. And I have to create an ID column basing on the city name it can be based on the alphabetical order
can any of the guys help me in this.

Comment: all the cars data should go into the same table. all files have same  column names, similarly with the trucks and bikes. An ID column should be created basing on the city name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am using SQL Server Express 2008 (R2) and with this I was able to export MS Excel File into my Database. I know at least three ways to do this:

```
 1) Using Import and Export Data (whether 32 bit or 64 bit).
 2) Using SQL per se
 3) Programmatically like using C# or VB.net
```

In **Import and Export Data** just go to your MS SQL Server under All Programs and from there follow the direction. You specify the `Data Source` as `MS Excel` and then you Identify your `Destination` and make sure you Identity to which `Database` you want to put it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In **Using SQL** you could simply use the following command just change accordingly to your own need.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=c:\CityName\DALLAS_Cars_2011.xls','select * from [sheet1$]')
```

However, if you encounter problem like :

```
 OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.
```

Try to add this lines:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=c:\CityName\DALLAS_Cars_2011.xls','select * from [sheet1$]')
```

Otherwise if you still encounter problem that probably means that your `MS Excel is 32 bit` and you are running on `64 bit SQL Server`. So, you are better off doing the 1st method.

Finally if you know **programming in VB.Net or C#** then you could probably code it like this:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strSQL As String
Dim lngRecsAff As Long
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<server>;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=<database>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>"

'Import by using OPENDATASOURCE.
strSQL = "SELECT * INTO XLImport6 FROM " & _
    "OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', " & _
    "'Data Source=C:\test\xltest.xls;" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Customers$]"
cn.Execute strSQL, lngRecsAff, adExecuteNoRecords
```

See source [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686)

Or you could also use a library from `EPPlus` like what I did in one of my program.

See its link [here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks Edper for your code.The code which you gave work for one city at a time but i have like more than 150 excel sheets i was looking for For each loop container to enumerate all the files.

Comment: Well you'll probably will be better off if you do it programmatically. You just identify the folder and then the program will just pick up all the Excel files and insert all those excel files into your database (specifically to a Table).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SSIS` to load the excel files into SQL Server.

1. Create 3 variables: File, City and Table
2. Create an expression for the City variable to retrieve the City part from File
3. Do the same for Table
4. Create a foreach file enumerator
5. Assign the fully qualified name to the File variable
6. Create a data flow task that contains an excel source and ole db destination
7. Create an excel connection which retrieves uses the File variable
8. Create an ole db connection, assign it to the ole db destination and choose the Table variable as destination table.

Example of expression for city:

If you're File variable contains: C:\temp\Dallas\Dallas_Trucks_2011.xls

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::File], FINDSTRING(@[User::File], "\\", 3) + 1, FINDSTRING(SUBSTRING(@[User::File], FINDSTRING(@[User::File], "\\", 3) + 1, 99), "_", 1) -1)
```

The expression should return `Dallas`. It retrieves the part betweent he third `\` and the first `_`

The following expression returns `Trucks` by retrieving the part between the first `_` and second `_`

```
SUBSTRING(@[User::File], FINDSTRING(@[User::File], "_", 1) + 1, FINDSTRING(SUBSTRING(@[User::File], FINDSTRING(@[User::File], "_", 1) + 1, 99), "_", 1) -1)
```

You can also add a derived column in the data flow task to add the City as a column.

**EDIT: I'm actually not 100% sure this will work with a dynamic Excel file and Table definition.**

Comment: This looks like the way to go. If the OP has access to SSIS it will be an awful lot easier and quicker for loading multiple files than writing and debugging handcrafted code. I'm pretty sure the above will work, but it may take a little digging around the SSIS configuration dialogs. Sadly, I no longer have access to SSIS myself, so I can't assist with that digging.